# GCC "undefined reference to" but symbols exist

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, name-mangling

Can I use shared libraries created by different versions of GCC and how?

I have `undefined reference to` errors while linking. But these names exist in the `so` libraries. I figured out that libs were built with older GCC version (2.8), I'm using current GCC version (4.7) and thus it seems that names are mangled differently:

Built by GCC **2.8.1**:

`setInfo__10SS7_HeaderUl`

Built by GCC **4.7.2**:

`_ZN10SS7_Header7setInfoEm`

and can't be resolved (right?).

Is there any way to use old shared libraries without rebuilding them? (Maybe I can recompile existing code using some backward compatibility flags, etc, to suit old libraries)

Comment: Looks like they've changed the name mangling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to use old shared libraries without rebuilding them?

No: gcc-2.x and 3.x are not ABI-compatible.

If you somehow managed to fix the mangling, you'd just get a crash because the object layout is completely different. The mangling was changed *precisely* to save you the trouble of debugging runtime crashes that would be very hard to understand.